# How to implement a complex IEnumerable<T> directly inside the type containing the IEnumerable<T> property?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have a generic collection implementation for various things that's inside:

```
public class ImageDocument
```

with properties like:

```
.Objects
.Effects
.Layers
```

each of which is basically `IEnumerable<T>`, but I also have separate calls that gives me the count for each of these, something like:

```
GetNumObjects()
GetNumEffects()
GetNumLayers()
```

but these are lower level members that I want to wrap as well as implement the above properties (`.Objects, .Effects, .Layers`) as `IEnumerable<T>`, also using lower level members like:

```
GetObject (int index)
GetEffect (int index)
GetLayer (int index)
```

I have my own `IEnumerable<T>` like interface that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

In the end I want these properties to be like this:

```
ICountableEnumerable Objects
ICountableEnumerable Effects
ICountableEnumerable Layers
```

so I could both enumerate them, access their counts (using the low level functions) as well as to be able to index them:

```
myImageDocument.Objects.Count, etc.
myImageDocument.Objects[4]
foreach ... myImageDocument.Objects ...
```

Can I implement these directly just like implementing `IEnumerable<T>` inside `ImageDocument` like:

```
   public IEnumerator<Objects> GetEnumerator()
   {
      foreach(...)
      {
         yield return obj;
      }
   }
```

or do I need an intermediate type for each of these properties? Something like:

```
ObjectCollection
EffectCollection
LayerCollection
```

that implements `ICountableEnumerable`?

Comment: sounds to me you should be exposing IList<T> instead of ICountableEnumerable. ICountableEnumerable doesn't make much sense... every IEnumerable *IS* countable, either by casting it to its underlaying collection or by looping through its content.

Comment: That's interesting idea, but for IList do I have to implement all these methods? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx Also I know IEnumerable is countable but I don't want to enumerate through 1M elements when the count is already know can just be returned in O(1).

Answer (score 4):

I would probably do something like:

```
class ImageDocument
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Effect> Effects { get { ... } }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Layer> Layers { get { ... } }
    ...
```

That way the user can use all the nice properties of ReadOnlyCollection, like count, etc.  The read-only-collection is a *wrapper* around a mutable collection; you can keep your mutable collection logic working as an implementation detail, and just expose a read-only wrapper on top of it.

Comment: Thanks Eric, so when I do this I will just create a new ReadOnlyCollection? But how I am gonna override the index and Count of it?

Comment: Also I don't know if it's important to mention but this is also very performance sensitive, I mean as fast as possible, so if there creating a new ReadOnlyCollection everytime is gonna be accessed, then I have to find something else. I guess I could store it internally right? That's what I do currently. In my ImageDocument, I store the collection and when requested return it where you have access to its count, indexing, etc.

Comment: Use `ReadOnlyCollection<string> = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(myList);`, where `myList` is of type `IList<string>` . [The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132476.aspx) states that this is an O(1) operation, but you do not need to recreate the `ReadOnlyCollection` every time the `get` method is called, since it is a wrapper, as Eric states.  You do not need to override `Count` or `Index`, as these are built in (and will work the same way as the underlying type's `Count` and `Index`.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am unsure about a few things. So I should use IList as the underlying type? Also you said I don't need to override Count or Index but in that case how can the runtime know how to call my functions? It has to explicitly do this: InternalImageDocument.GetEffectCount(), etc.

Comment: @Joan: `IList` is an interface and cannot be an underlying type.  Whatever you choose as a type must implement `IList` (e.g., `List`), because this is a requirement of `ReadOnlyCollection`. Note that `List` has an `AsReadOnly` method that can also be used to make a `ReadOnlyCollection`.  I am pretty sure `ReadOnlyCollection` is implemented using basic [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). When you call `Count` or other members of `ReadOnlyCollection`, it knows how to call `Count` on the type it is wrapping because the `IList` interface has a `Count` method.

Answer (score 2):

What if within your class you held the collections as List < T >? Then your IEnumerable < T > .Objects, et al, can return the List which would be enumerable AND optimized for index and count by LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you do this? How can I override their members for indexing, counting, etc?

Comment: You don't have to - if LINQ 'sees' that the IEnumerable it's working on is really a IList it will call IList.Count or IList.Index when you call the LINQ extension methods on the IEnumerable.

Comment: LINQ does this for anything 'count-ish' - Take, Skip, etc. All check the underlying type for optimizaitons like this.

Comment: Sorry to add another comment - Jon Skeet has had two dozen blog posts where he re-implements LINQ-to-objects and you can read about these optimizations. Very interesting.

Comment: Yes but how will IList.Count will call my GetObjectCount, etc functions in the lower level types?

Comment: Are these on-demand collections or something? I guess that's what's not clear to me.

Comment: Maybe you need to refactor ImageDocument so that you can implement custom-IList-implementing collections that encapsulate your special-count logic.

Comment: No they are not on demand, they exist in memory. So all they do is to give you access to the ones you want like Layer[4] or enumerate them, etc. But indexing is a must per the sdk I am using.

Comment: So there you go - store them in a List<T> and return the list as IEnumerable and let LINQ do its magic.

Comment: Thanks, just saw your answer but I can't do that either, because the data is changing within the application. So say I returned all the Effects, and a minute later the user adds/removes them, then next time when I access the either the stored list will be invalid or I have to recreate it. Is that what you were asking with on demand? Because I thought you mean if they were on demand as in the underlying low level stuff. I guess my stuff is on demand.

Comment: Also can you please show me some examples on Jon Skeets LINQ optimizations like if they can make linq to use my methods for counting, indexing, etc, surely that would be much much better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest declaring a struct type for each of the different styles of enumeration; the struct should hold an immutable reference to the base collection, and implement IEnumerable<appropriateType> and publicly expose a GetEnumerator method, which would in turn call baseThing.GetLayersEnumerator() or some other similar function.  Such an approach would avoid boxing in many common usage scenarios, and--unlike the structs returned by things like List.GetEnumerator--would exhibit reference semantics whether or not it was boxed.